# C# HttpListener sending data to client at any time

Tags: c#, httplistener

I know how to reply to client's requests using `HttpListener`, but I want to send data to a client without any client request (i.e. updating the page with new data when available). Is there a way to do this? Or is the easiest way to make clients send an update request in set intervals?

Comment: Read up on WebSocket and SignalR

Comment: The way to do this without WebSocket is polling. The client periodically asks for updates.